# Using aliases names of columns in where clause

Tags: mysql, alias, where-clause, having-clause

I have given a alis name for all my fields in the select clause. I am not able to use these names in my where clause.

I tried to use having clause, but it takes more time then usual where clause. Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Do you have any examples of what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices for this,

One, use the whole expression in the `WHERE` clause,

```
SELECT Hello, 
       DATE(CURDATE()) cur_date
FROM   tableName
WHERE  DATE(CURDATE()) >= CURDATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

or Two, wrap it in a subquery

```
SELECT *
FROM
       (
           SELECT Hello, 
                  DATE(CURDATE()) cur_date
           FROM   tableName
       ) subAlias
WHERE  cur_date >= CURDATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```